Trigger Cloud Function from Firebase Extension: missing events
Our Firebase project is integrated with both our iOS and Android apps (two apps within a single project). We've implemented a custom Firebase Extension designed to trigger on all first_open events. However, I've observed that the extension only triggers for about 75% of the total events. For instance, while we receive approximately 12,000 first_open events daily, the extension triggers only around 9,000 times. Notably, there are no errors reported from the associated Cloud Function (Also, Retry on failure is On). Is there any configure or any setting that I need to aware to make sure the Function is triggered for all (first_open) events?
